# WordPress Loop Wrap Div Around Each Set of 3 Columns

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, zurb-foundation

I would like to create a WordPress loop that wraps a DIV around each set of 3 columns. Essentially, I want this to be the loops output:

```
<div class="row"> // This row does have 3 sets of columns, so it will create another row
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
    <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
    <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
    <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> // Since this row doesn't have three sets of columns, so it does not create another row
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
    <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">
    <--Content Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current loop code:

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=-4'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">

        <--Content Stuff-->

    <?php if ($i % 3 == 0) {echo '</div></div><div class="row"><div class="large-4 medium-4 columns panel grid">';} ?>

    <?php $i++; endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- end .panel -->
</div>      

<?php else : ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'missing' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

However, this ends up rendering a completely blank page which leads me to believe i have PHP errors - I just don't know where.

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247770/loop-through-wordpress-posts-and-wrap-each-x-post-in-a-div

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an additional closing of while statement

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Remove the above line as you have already closed the while statement

Comment: I removed that extra endwhile, however, the page is still blank. Thanks for helping me get rid of that extra tag though - one step closer!